# Reverse Ajax responseText detection

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, comet

This function gets called when an ajax requests readyState == 3,

```
function(context, xhrobj, itself){
    //Test if context.responseText is available here.

    var text = context.responseText;
    //Do stuff
}
```

How would I be able to test if context.responseText is available? I am currently doing this,

```
if ($.browser.msie) return false;
```

But I really don't want to do browser detection, **Is there a way to detect if context.responseText is unavailabe?** Specifically for IE7/8, I am not supporting 6 or below.

I've tried,

```
if('responseText' in context) return false;
```

which doesn't work because it is in context, just not available, and

```
try{context.responseText;} catch(x){return false;}
```

but this seems like a hack.

Comment: I'd just go with the last `try/catch` one you listed. It seems like a hack, sure, but that's what browsers sometimes force you to do. Also, `readyState == 3` can be called multiple times, if I remember correctly. Why don't you wait until 4?

Comment: It's comet, I'm pushing json but not closing the connection, so I can push data back to the browser many times before having to reset the connecton.

Comment: the `try/catch` way doesnt seem so hacky to me (not that im an authority on the matter)... i think it's a good solution to your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Context will not have initialized the response object whether text, xml.  Therefore, unless you implement some sort of an observer for the actual creation/initialization/population of the response the 2nd try...catch seems to do what you need it to do.  It is not a hack, as the context.responseText isn't created and therefore, uninitialized.

I will continue to monitor this thread, but I think IMHO your approach is appropriate.

best of luck,

Josh

Comment: I call it a hack because I don't believe in using a catch statement for normal program flow, but thats just semantics. As I am a newish js developer I was hoping there was some other cleaner way of detecting IE's terribleness :), thanks for the affirmation.